# Detecting page refresh c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, web-applications, razor-pages

I have created a document upload site with asp.net core web app's, and I have encountered a small bug but I'm not sure how to fix it.

On my site, you first create a 'file' like so:

[image: Create a file]

It then appears in a list like so:

[image: file list]

And when you press upload attachment, it passes the id from the previous table to ensure it uploads to the correct file.

[image: upload attachment]

The code behind the upload page is as below, and the error is if you press upload before choosing a file, it does a page refresh to display an error and then the ID passed through before has been lost, so myInv ends up being null.

```
using FarmersPortal.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using File = FarmersPortal.Data.File;

namespace FarmersPortal.Pages.Admin
{
    [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
    public class UploadModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly filedbContext _context;

        public UploadModel(filedbContext context)
        {

            _context = context;
        }
        public int? myID { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public IFormFile file { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public void OnGet(int? id)
        {
            myID = id;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public File File { get; set; }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (file.Length > 0 && file.Length < 300000)
                {
                    var myInv = _context.Files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ID);
                    var date = DateTime.Today;

                    using (var target = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(target);
                        myInv.UploadDate = date;
                        myInv.Attachment = target.ToArray();
                    }
                    if (myInv == null)
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File = myInv;
                    }
                    _context.Files.Update(myInv);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

            }

            if (File.FileType == "Purchase Order")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./PurchaseOrders");
            }
            else if (File.FileType == "Remittance")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Remittance");
            }
            else if (File.FileType == "Haulage Self Bill")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./HaulageSelfBill");
            }
            else if (File.FileType == "Growers Return")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./GrowersReturn");
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to work my way around this, any ideas?

```
@page
@model FarmersPortal.Pages.Admin.UploadModel
@{
}

<h1 style="color:white">Upload File</h1>

<style>
    body {
        background-image: url("http://10.48.1.215/PORTAL/hero-range-1.jpg");
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p style="color:white">Upload file</p>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ID" value="@Model.myID" />
                    <input asp-for="file" class="form-control" accept=".pdf" type="file" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="file" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Above is the front end code.

Comment: Can you provide the frontend code of current page? Do you wanna add a client validation to achieve that when user click `upload` button without upload any file, The page will stop uploading the form and show an error like: `you must select a file`?

Comment: @XinranShen I have added the front end code onto the post. Yes that would be great, I thought adding the `<span asp-validation-for="file" class="text-white"></span>` would help but it didn't, it made an error come up but gave the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom the error message

```
[BindProperty]
[Required(ErrorMessage ="You must select a file before upload this form")]
public IFormFile file { get; set; }
```

And you also need to add Jquery validation library to your view:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

Then when user don't select any file and click the upload button, View will show error message and stop uploading the form.

[image]